# Get cluster assignments in Weka

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I have a CSV file as follows:

```
id,at1,at2,at3
1072,0.5,0.2,0.7
1092,0.2,0.5,0.7
...
```

I've loaded it in in Weka for clustering:

```
DataSource source = new DataSource("test.csv");
Instances data = source.getDataSet();
kmeans.buildClusterer(data);
```

**Question #1:** How do I set the first column as an ID? ie. ignoring the first column for clustering purposes.

I then try to print out the assignments:

```
int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments();
int i = 0;
for (int clusterNum : assignments) {
    System.out.printf("Instance %d -> Cluster %d \n", i, clusterNum);
    i++;
}
```

This prints:

```
Instance 1 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 2 -> Cluster 2
...
```

**Question #2:** How do I refer to the ID when printing out the assignments? For example:

```
Instance 1072 -> Cluster 0
Instance 1092 -> Cluster 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your life would be much easier if you use Windows version of Weka with GUI.

In cluster tab there is a button for ignoring attributes like ID.

And for Id to cluster assignments; after your are done with clustering algorithm you chose, right click the result on left of the screen, then visualize results and then save.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old question, but I came here looking for an answer as well, and then was able to figure it out myself, so putting my solution here for the next person with this problem. In my case, the clustering component is part of a Java application, so I don't have the option of using the Weka workbench. Here is what I did to pull out the id along with the cluster assignments.

```
int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments();
for (int i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++) {
  int id = (int) data.instance(i).value(0); // cast from double
  System.out.printf("ID %d -> Cluster %d \n", id, assignments[i]);
}
```

Unlike the OP, I did not build my Instances from DataSource.getDataSet(), I built this manually from a database table, but the id field was the first one in my case as well, so I think the code above should work. I had a custom distance function that skipped the id field when computing similarity.

Comment: How about clustering?? did you do anything to ignore the id column for clustering purposes??!!

Comment: Thanks, you helped me out! Small thing though; I changed `i < assignments` for `i < assignment.lengths` to make it work.